# facebook api - fb:registration and permissions issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i'm working with the facebook sdk for php and want the users to sit on my own database but still to get permissions of them.

my very basic use of the

i want to register users to my site via facebook, but i still want to be able to post to thier wall.   i thought about only using the facebook login method but then i have no way to ask my customers (Via registration) what is their phone number and the phone number is the most important part i need from the people who register.

i tried to add the scope params to my `<fb:registration` tag but it seems to ignore it. when i only use the login method via `<fb:login-button` the permissions issue seems to work.

this is my exact flow:
first, i call the fb:login-button to determine if the client is already reistered:

```
<fb:login-button scope="publish_stream,user_checkins,email" registration-url="/register" /></fb:login-button>
```

then, on the registration page i have this code:

```
<fb:registration
fields='[{"name":"name"},{"name":"gender"},{"name":"email"},{"name":"birthday"},{"name":"location"},{"name":"phone2","description":"mobile phone","type":"text"}]'
redirect-uri="XXXXXX"
fb_only="true"
scope="read_stream,publish_stream" 
width="530">
```

when the user comes back from facebook i use this code:

```
require_once('facebook-sdk/src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => $GLOBALS['facebookAppID'], 'secret' => $GLOBALS['facebookAppSecret']));
$customerArray = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

that's works great and create the customer record on my database. but - it does not give the permission i need to post on my user wall.

Comment: Can you include some code showing how your are setting the access_token

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask for user permissions in registration using this plugin, but you can do a work around asking for permissions before showing the form. You can make a call to FB.login popup and after the user gives you permissions in the callback function you can show the registration form (which could be hidden while the user accept the permissions).